# Python Tkinter GUI working only once

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hello all Pythonian folks, I am relatively new to Tkinter and I am currently working on a GUI that thatallows an user to choose elements from a given list, then put them in any given order and add any optional prefixes/suffixes. The program works fine the first time it is called, but when I try to call it a second time, it just will not update correctly.

My code is as below for the created class (I've put an executable part at the bottom so as to give you an idea of my problem, List 0 is any given list, List 1st is what we obtain from the 1st call and List 2nd should be what is obtained from the 2nd call, had this problem not shown up):

```
import Tkinter as TK
class SelecParamOrdered(TK.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master, listInit=[], listFinal=[], TITLE="Parameter selection", TEXTE="Here, specific instructions", number = 5):
        TK.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.TEXTE = TEXTE
        self.TITLE = TITLE
        listInit.sort()
        listFinal.sort()
    #
        listTemp=[]
        for elt in listInit:
            if elt.replace(' ','')=='':
                pass
            elif not elt in listTemp:
                listTemp.append(elt)
        listInit=listTemp
    #
        listTemp=[]
        for elt in listFinal:
            if (not elt in listTemp) and (elt in listInit):
                listTemp.append(elt)
        listFinal=listTemp
    #
        listTemp=[]
        for elt in listInit:
            if not elt in listFinal:
                listTemp.append(elt)
        listInit=listTemp
        self.listInit=listInit
        self.listFinal=listFinal
        self.indexI=0
        self.indexF=0
        self.number = number
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title(self.TITLE)
        self.grid()        
        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(4, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(5, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(6, pad=3)       
        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(4, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(6, pad=3)
    # Labels texte
        text_param = TK.Label(self,text='Parametre')
        text_param.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky='W')
        text_order = TK.Label(self,text='Ordre')
        text_order.grid(column=1, row=8, columnspan = 3)
        text_prefix = TK.Label(self,text='Prefixe')
        text_prefix.grid(column=5,row=8)
        text_suffix = TK.Label(self,text='Suffixe')
        text_suffix.grid(column=6, row=8)
        txt = TK.Label(self, text=self.TEXTE)
        txt.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=7, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
        t1= TK.Label(self, text="Liste initiale")
        t1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
        t2 = TK.Label(self, text="Liste finale")
        t2.grid(row=1, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
    #
        self.listboxInit=TK.Listbox(self, selectmode=TK.EXTENDED)
        self.listboxInit.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, sticky=TK.N+TK.W+TK.E+TK.S)
        self.listboxInit.bind('<Double-1>', self.listInit_event)
        self.sbInit = TK.Scrollbar(self)
        self.sbInit.config(command=self.listboxInit.yview)
        self.listboxInit.config(yscrollcommand=self.sbInit.set)
        self.sbInit.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky=TK.N+TK.S)
    #
        self.listboxFinal = TK.Listbox(self, selectmode=TK.EXTENDED)
        self.listboxFinal.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, sticky=TK.N+TK.W+TK.E+TK.S)
        self.listboxFinal.bind('<Double-1>', self.listFinal_event)
        self.sbFinal = TK.Scrollbar(self)
        self.sbFinal.config(command=self.listboxFinal.yview)
        self.listboxFinal.config(yscrollcommand=self.sbFinal.set)
        self.sbFinal.grid(row=2, column=6, rowspan=4, sticky=TK.N+TK.S)
        self.fillListboxes()
        add = TK.Button(self, text="==>", command=self.addParam)
        add.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
        rem = TK.Button(self, text="<==", command=self.removeParam)
        rem.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
        addT = TK.Button(self, text=">>>", command=self.addAllParam)
        addT.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
        remT = TK.Button(self, text="<<<", command=self.removeAllParam)
        remT.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
        send = TK.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.sendList)
        send.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=7, sticky=TK.W+TK.E)
        sendall = TK.Button(self,text='OK',command=self.sendAll)
        sendall.grid(column=0, row=self.number+9, columnspan=7, sticky='WE')
    # Une boucle par label/parametre
        liste_options = range(1,self.number+1)        
        for i in range(self.number):
        # Label Ordre
            exec('self.text_var_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.StringVar()')
            exec('self.text_param_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.Label(self,text=\'\', textvariable=self.text_var_'+str(i+1)+')')
            exec('self.text_param_'+str(i+1)+'.grid(column=0, row='+str(i+9)+')')

        # Liste deroulante
            exec('self.v_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.IntVar()')
            exec('self.v_'+str(i+1)+'.set(None)')
            exec('om_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.OptionMenu(self,self.v_'+str(i+1)+',*liste_options)')
            exec('om_'+str(i+1)+'.grid(column=1,row='+str(i+9)+',sticky=\'WE\')')

        # Entree prefixe
            exec('self.p_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.StringVar()')
            exec('self.entry_prefix_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.Entry(self,textvariable=self.p_'+str(i+1)+',width=10)')
            exec('self.entry_prefix_'+str(i+1)+'.grid(column=5,row='+str(i+9)+')')

        # Entree suffixe
            exec('self.s_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.StringVar()')
            exec('self.entry_suffix_'+str(i+1)+' = TK.Entry(self,textvariable=self.s_'+str(i+1)+',width=10)')
            exec('self.entry_suffix_'+str(i+1)+'.grid(column=6,row='+str(i+9)+')')

    def fillInit(self,list):
        list2=[]
        for elt in list:
            if (not elt in list2) and (not elt in self.listFinal):
                list2.append(elt)
        list2.sort()
        self.listInit=list2
        self.fillListboxes()
    def fillFinal(self,list):
        for elt in list:
            if not elt in self.listFinal:
                self.listFinal.append(elt)
                if elt in self.listInit:
                    self.listInit.remove(elt)
        self.listFinal.sort()
        self.fillListboxes()

    def fillListboxes(self):
        self.listboxInit.delete(0,TK.END)
        for p in self.listInit:
            self.listboxInit.insert(TK.END,p)
        self.listboxFinal.delete(0,TK.END)
        for p in self.listFinal:
            self.listboxFinal.insert(TK.END,p)
        self.listboxInit.see(self.indexI)
        self.listboxFinal.see(self.indexF)

    def addParam(self):
        index = self.listboxInit.curselection()
        for i in index:
            self.listInit.remove(self.listboxInit.get(i))
            if not self.listboxInit.get(i) in self.listFinal:
                self.listFinal.append(self.listboxInit.get(i))
        if len(index)>0:
        if index[0]>0:
            self.indexI=int(index[0])-1
    else:
        self.indexI=0
        self.listFinal.sort()
        self.fillListboxes()

    def removeParam(self):
        index = self.listboxFinal.curselection()
        for i in index:
            self.listFinal.remove(self.listboxFinal.get(i))
        if not self.listboxFinal.get(i) in self.listInit:
                self.listInit.append(self.listboxFinal.get(i))
    if len(index)>0:
        if index[0]>0:
            self.indexF=int(index[0])-1
    else:
        self.indexF=0
        self.listInit.sort()
        self.fillListboxes()

    def addAllParam(self):
        for elt in self.listInit:
        if not elt in self.listFinal:
                self.listFinal.append(elt)
        self.listFinal.sort()
        self.listInit=[]
    self.indexI=0
        self.fillListboxes()

    def removeAllParam(self):
        for elt in self.listFinal:
        if not elt in self.listInit:
                self.listInit.append(elt)
        self.listInit.sort()
        self.listFinal=[]
    self.indexF=0
        self.fillListboxes()

    def listInit_event(self, event):
        self.addParam()

    def listFinal_event(self, event):
        self.removeParam()

    def sendList(self):
        for i in range(len(self.listFinal)):
            exec('self.text_var_'+str(i+1)+'.set(self.listFinal[i])')
        self.master.update_idletasks()

    def sendAll(self):
        listOut = []
        pOut = []
        sOut = []
        for i in range(len(self.listFinal)):
            exec('num = self.v_'+str(i+1)+'.get()')
        #print 'Num is: ',num
            for j in range(len(self.listFinal)):
            #print '  Index is: ',j+1
                if num == j+1:
                #print '  Condition OK'
                    exec('listOut.append(self.text_var_'+str(j+1)+'.get())')
                    exec('pOut.append(self.p_'+str(j+1)+'.get())')
                    exec('sOut.append(self.s_'+str(j+1)+'.get())')
        self.quit()
        return listOut, pOut, sOut
```

---

The function I use to call it, as well as the main, are as follows:

```
def getchosenlist(listInit=[],listFinal=[], TITLE="Parameter selection", TEXTE="Here, specific instructions"):
    root = TK.Tk()
    app = SelecParamOrdered(root,listInit,listFinal,TITLE,TEXTE)
    root.mainloop()
    return app.sendAll()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    liste_param = []
    for i in range(10):
        liste_param.append('Parameter'+str(i+1))
    print ' List 0:\n',liste_param
    list1 = getchosenlist(liste_param)
    print ' List 1st:\n',list1
    list2 = getchosenlist(liste_param)
    print ' List 2nd:\n',list2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please read this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: or read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe not the sole problem since, as mentioned by comments, your example code is too long regarding conventions of this site (see for instance [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for feedback on significant piece of code).*

Your code exhibit a common error among newcomers to python, the use of an empty list as a default value for keyword arguments (in at least `getchosenlist`  and `SelecParamOrdered.__init__`). This empty list is shared amongst every call of your method an thus, appending to it whill accumulate results over time. You can read a detailed explanation  on [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) .

What you probably want to achieve can be used with the pattern:

```
def foo(arg = None):
    if arg is None:
        arg = []
    (...)
```